# KnockOut Drag And Drop Cause Duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Here is my first **template:**

```
<script type="text/html" id="Testing">


              <!-- ko if: $data.CLASSIFICATION_NAME().toLowerCase() == 'general'  -->

         <!-- ko if: $data.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE().toLowerCase() == AttributeEnum.NumberRange -->
        <li>
            <div class="divFilterRow">
                <div class="divFilterCol">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED, attr:{'id': ATTRIBUTE_NAME}, click: function(){checkedCallback($data); return true; }" />       
                </div>
                <div class="divFilterCol divFilterCph">
                    <label data-bind="    text: ATTRIBUTE_NAME, attr:{'for': ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'attributetooltip': ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION}"></label>
                    <a class="iClose" href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="    click: $data.removeSelectedAttribute , style: {display: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED() ? 'block' : 'none'}"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iClearBoth" />
            <div data-bind="    visible: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED">
                <div data-bind="    template: {name:  'sliderTemplate',foreach: filterSliderValues} "></div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <!-- /ko -->



          <!-- ko if: $data.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE().toLowerCase() == AttributeEnum.MultipleChoiceList -->
        <li>
           <div class="divFilterRow">
                <div class="divFilterCol">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED, attr:{'id': ATTRIBUTE_NAME}, click: function(){checkedCallback($data); return true; }" />
                </div>
                <div class="divFilterCol divFilterCph">
                    <label data-bind="text: ATTRIBUTE_NAME, attr:{'for': ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'attributetooltip': ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION }"></label>
                    <a class="iClose" href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $data.removeSelectedAttribute , style: {display: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED() ? 'block' : 'none'}"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iClearBoth" />
            <div data-bind="visible: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED">
                <div data-bind="    template: {name:  'sliderTemplate',foreach: filterSliderValues} "></div>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: ISATTRIBUTESELECTED">
                <div  data-bind="dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'modal': true,
    'resizable': false, width: 950, draggable: false, closeOnEscape: false 
                @*,buttons: {
                                'Apply': function () {
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
                            } *@
},
    dialogVisible: isDialogOpen" 
                class="iSmallDialog" >
                    <div class="HelpBar" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 12px;">

                        <div class="divHelpContent" data-bind="text: ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        Please select options from the list below:
                    </div>


                    <div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 200px;" class="ListOptions">





                    <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'TestingTemplate', data: filterListOptions },class:'ui-sortable'"></ul>



    </div>

                      <div class="iDialogSubmit">
                        <button data-bind="click: $data.onDialogCloseCallback,enable: isOptionsSelected" class="active">TestingApply</button>

                        <button class="btnInactive" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click: $data.onDialogClose" aria-hidden="true">TestingCancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </script>
```

Here is my second **template:**

```
 <script id="TestingTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li><label data-bind="text: Value, attr:{'for': Value().replace(/ /g,'_')}"></label></li>
    </script>
```

**Here is the way i call it:**

```
     <div class="LHSListItem">General</div>
                    <div class="contentDivWithPadding fixHeightAccordian">
                        <div class="divAccordianContent" id="divAttributes_General">


   <ul data-bind="template: { name : 'Testing', foreach : filterData} "></ul>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

**Here is my output:**

[image]

**When i drag `Active` or `Out of Study`,output becomes as follow:**

[image]

**Here is My Model:**

```
 var extendedAttributeMapping = {
        //'ignore': ["ISATTRIBUTESELECTED"],
        create: function (options) {
            var extendedAttributeModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);

            //drop down for SECTION attribute
            extendedAttributeModel.selectedFilterStateforSection = ko.observable();

            // extendedAttributeModel.sectionCounter = ko.observable("2509");
            extendedAttributeModel.removeSelectedAttribute = function (modelObject) { 

                modelObject.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(false);

                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE().toLowerCase() == AttributeEnum.MultipleChoiceList)
                {
                    modelObject.isDialogOpen(false);
                    extendedAttributeModel.onAttributeUncheckCallback(modelObject);
                    //modelObject.OptionsCountLabel("");
                    //modelObject.isOptionsSelected(false);
                    //modelObject.OptionsSelectedCount(0);
                }
                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE().toLowerCase() == AttributeEnum.NumberRange)
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.resetSlider(modelObject);
                }
                sltModel.getsectionCount();
                $(document).trigger('OnApplyAttribute');
            };
            extendedAttributeModel.resetSlider = function(modelObject){
                var minCurrentVal = modelObject.filterSliderValues()[0].MINCURRENT();
                var maxCurrentVal = modelObject.filterSliderValues()[0].MAXCURRENT();
                modelObject.filterSliderValues()[0].min(minCurrentVal);
                modelObject.filterSliderValues()[0].max(maxCurrentVal);
            };

            //jquery UI Dialog custom Helper events
            extendedAttributeModel.onDialogCloseCallback = function(modelObject){
                //alert("Callback");
                //debugger;
                modelObject.isDialogOpen(false);

                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_CODE().toLowerCase() == "section")
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.getSectionAttributeOptionsOnApply(modelObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.getOptionsOnApply(modelObject);
                }

                sltModel.getsectionCount();
                extendedAttributeModel.setDefaultModified(modelObject);
                $(document).trigger('OnApplyAttribute');
            };
            extendedAttributeModel.onDialogOpen = function(){

                extendedAttributeModel.isDialogOpen(true);
                //modelObject.isDialogOpen(true);
                //modelObject.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(true);
            };


            //SECTION ATTRIBUTE IMPLEMENETATION- EXTENDED MODEL
            //SECTION CHECKBOXES SELECTION
            extendedAttributeModel.getSectionAttributeOptionsOnApply = function(modelObject) {
                var totalSelected = 0;
                var selectedAttributeID = modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_ID();

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterddlSectionListOptions(), function(outeritem) {

                    // sltModel.setSectionAttributeOriginalStateName(outeritem);

                    if(outeritem.sectionList().length > 0)
                    {
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(outeritem.sectionList(),function(item){

                            if (item.isSectionSelected()) {
                                totalSelected++;
                                //  outeritem.isSelected(true);
                                //highlight selected states
                            }
                            item.SavedSectionCheckedState(item.isSectionSelected());  
                        });
                    }

                });
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsCountLabel("(" + totalSelected + ")");
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsSelectedCount(totalSelected);
                if(totalSelected > 0)
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(true);
                else
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(false);
                    extendedAttributeModel.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(false);
                }
            };

            //ali method code starts
            extendedAttributeModel.isTaskSelected = function(task) {
                return task === self.selectedTask();  
            };
            //ali method code ends
            extendedAttributeModel.OnSectionAttributeOptionSelect = function(modelObject,parentObject){
                //SavedSectionCheckedState
                //isSectionModified
                //isSectionSelected
                //sectionId
                //sectionName
                //stateCode
                modelObject.isSectionModified(true);
                var  totalSelected=0;

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions(), function(outeritem) {

                    if(outeritem.sectionList().length > 0)
                    {
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(outeritem.sectionList(),function(item){

                            if (item.isSectionSelected()) {
                                totalSelected++;
                            }  

                        });
                    }

                });

                //sections selected per state
                var sectionSelectedPerState=0;
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].sectionList(), function(item) {

                    if (item.isSectionSelected()) {
                        sectionSelectedPerState++;
                    }
                });
                parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].sectionSelectedCount = (sectionSelectedPerState);

                var indexCounter = parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].Text().indexOf("(");

                var stateNameWithCount = 0;
                if(indexCounter > -1)
                {
                    stateNameWithCount = parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].Text().substring(0,indexCounter);
                }
                else{
                    stateNameWithCount = parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].Text();
                }

                if(sectionSelectedPerState == 0)
                    parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].Text($.trim(stateNameWithCount));
                else
                    parentObject.filterddlSectionListOptions()[sltModel.SectionAttributeStateIndex()].Text($.trim($.trim(stateNameWithCount) + "    ("+sectionSelectedPerState+")"));
                //sections selected per state


                if(totalSelected > 0)
                {
                    parentObject.isOptionsSelected(true);
                }
                else
                {parentObject.isOptionsSelected(false);}

            };


            extendedAttributeModel.getSectionAttributeOptionsSelectedCount = function(modelObject) {

                var totalSelected = 0;
                var perStateCounter = 0;
                var selectedAttributeID = modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_ID();

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterddlSectionListOptions(), function(outeritem) {



                    if(outeritem.sectionList().length > 0)
                    {
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(outeritem.sectionList(),function(item){
                            //if user unchecks checked and press cancel
                            if(item.isSectionModified()) {


                                item.isSectionSelected(item.SavedSectionCheckedState());
                                //if(!item.SavedSectionCheckedState())
                                //sltModel.setSectionAttributeOriginalStateName(outeritem);
                            }

                            if (item.isSectionSelected()) {
                                totalSelected++;
                                perStateCounter++;

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    sltModel.setSectionAttributeOriginalStateName(outeritem,perStateCounter);
                    perStateCounter = 0;

                });





                //setting the state name for selected sections
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsCountLabel("(" + totalSelected + ")");
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsSelectedCount(totalSelected);
                if(totalSelected > 0)
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(true);
                else
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(false);
                    extendedAttributeModel.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(false);
                }
            };
            //END OF SECTION ATTRIBUTE IMPLEMENETATION- EXTENDED MODEL



            extendedAttributeModel.OnOptionSelect = function(modelObject,parentObject){
                modelObject.isModified(true);                 
                var  totalSelected=0;
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(parentObject.filterListOptions(), function(item) {
                    if(modelObject.childObjects()==null)
                    {
                        if (item.isSelected()) {
                            totalSelected++;
                        }
                    }
                });

                //Get All the child elements for the selected item
                //if the selected option is checked then check all the child options
                //else vice versa
                if(modelObject.childObjects()!=null){
                    var isChecked = modelObject.isSelected();
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.childObjects(), function(item) {
                        //item.isModified(true);
                        item.isSelected(isChecked);
                        totalSelected++;
                    });
                }

                if(totalSelected > 0)
                {
                    parentObject.isOptionsSelected(true);
                }
                else
                {parentObject.isOptionsSelected(false);}

            };

            //new event added for the child options 
            extendedAttributeModel.OnChildOptionSelect = function(modelObject,parentContext, parentContextParentObject, parentObject){
                modelObject.isModified(true);
                var totalChildSelected=0;
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(parentObject.childObjects(), function(item) {
                    if (item.isSelected()) 
                    {
                        totalChildSelected++;
                    }
                });
                if(totalChildSelected == parentObject.childObjects().length)
                {
                    parentObject.isSelected(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    parentObject.isSelected(false);
                }
                if(totalChildSelected > 0)
                {
                    parentContextParentObject.isOptionsSelected(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    parentContextParentObject.isOptionsSelected(false);
                }
            };
            //eof child option event

            extendedAttributeModel.setDefaultModified = function(modelObject){

                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_CODE().toLowerCase() == "section")
                {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterddlSectionListOptions(), function(outeritem) {

                        if(outeritem.sectionList().length > 0)
                        {
                            ko.utils.arrayForEach(outeritem.sectionList(),function(item){

                                item.isSectionModified(false);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterListOptions(),function(elem){
                        elem.isModified(false);
                    });
                }
            };
            //instead of using click event , binding applied to observable property itself to show PopUp
            // extendedAttributeModel.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED.subscribe(function(value) {
            extendedAttributeModel.checkedCallback = function(modelObject,SOURCE){

                if(SOURCE == "LABEL")
                {
                    modelObject.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(true);
                }
                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE().toLowerCase() == AttributeEnum.MultipleChoiceList)
                {  
                    extendedAttributeModel.setDefaultModified(modelObject);



                    if(modelObject.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED())
                    {
                        modelObject.isDialogOpen(true);

                        //if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE.toLowerCase()=="list")
                        //{


                        //}
                    }
                    else
                    {  
                        modelObject.isDialogOpen(false);
                        extendedAttributeModel.onAttributeUncheckCallback(modelObject);
                        sltModel.getsectionCount();
                        $(document).trigger('OnApplyAttribute');
                    }

                }
                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_TYPE().toLowerCase() == AttributeEnum.NumberRange)
                { 
                    if(!modelObject.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED())
                    {
                        extendedAttributeModel.resetSlider(modelObject);
                    }
                    sltModel.getsectionCount();
                    $(document).trigger('OnApplyAttribute');    
                }


            };
            // },extendedAttributeModel);

            extendedAttributeModel.onDialogClose = function(modelObject){
                //alert("Close");
                //debugger;
                modelObject.isDialogOpen(false);

                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_CODE().toLowerCase() == "section")
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.getSectionAttributeOptionsSelectedCount(modelObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.getOptionsSelectedCount(modelObject);
                }

            };
            //Helper functions for label count selected Options
            extendedAttributeModel.OptionsCountLabel = ko.observable();
            extendedAttributeModel.OptionsSelectedCount = ko.observable();
            extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected = ko.observable();

            extendedAttributeModel.getOptionsSelectedCount = function(modelObject) {

                debugger;
                var totalSelected = 0;
                var selectedAttributeID = modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_ID();

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterListOptions(), function(item) {

                    //Checkbox is checked but cancel button clicked
                    //if (item.isSelected() && item.isModified()) {
                    //    item.isSelected(item.SavedCheckedState());
                    //}
                    //if user unchecks checked and press cancel
                    if(item.isModified()) {

                        item.isSelected(item.SavedCheckedState());
                    }

                    if (item.isSelected()) {
                        totalSelected++;
                    }

                });
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsCountLabel("(" + totalSelected + ")");
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsSelectedCount(totalSelected);
                if(totalSelected > 0)
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(true);
                else
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(false);
                    extendedAttributeModel.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(false);
                }
            };

            extendedAttributeModel.getOptionsOnApply = function(modelObject) {
                debugger;
                var totalSelected = 0;
                var selectedAttributeID = modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_ID();
                var i=0;
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterListOptions(), function(item) {


                    if(modelObject.filterListOptions()[i].childObjects()==null)
                    {
                        if (item.isSelected()) {
                            totalSelected++;
                        }
                    }


                    //Get All the child elements for the selected item
                    //if the selected option is checked then check all the child options
                    //else vice versa
                    if(modelObject.filterListOptions()[i].childObjects()!=null){
                        //var isChecked = modelObject.filterListOptions()[i].isSelected();
                        //if(isChecked){

                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterListOptions()[i].childObjects(), function(item) {

                            if( item.isSelected())
                            {
                                totalSelected++;
                            }
                        });

                        //}


                    }





                    //if (item.isSelected()) {
                    //    totalSelected++;

                    //}
                    item.SavedCheckedState(item.isSelected()); 
                    i++;
                });
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsCountLabel("(" + totalSelected + ")");
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsSelectedCount(totalSelected);
                if(totalSelected > 0)
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(true);
                else
                {
                    extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(false);
                    extendedAttributeModel.ISATTRIBUTESELECTED(false);
                }
            };

            //extendedAttributeModel.getOnlySelectedCount = function(modelObject) {
            //    var totalSelected = 0;
            //    var selectedAttributeID = modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_ID();

            //    ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterListOptions(), function(item) {

            //        if (item.isSelected()) {
            //            totalSelected++;
            //        }
            //    });
            //    return totalSelected;
            //};



            extendedAttributeModel.onAttributeUncheckCallback = function(modelObject) {

                if(modelObject.ATTRIBUTE_CODE().toLowerCase() == "section")
                {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelObject.filterddlSectionListOptions(), function(outeritem) {

                        sltModel.setSectionAttributeOriginalStateName(outeritem,-1);

                        if(outeritem.sectionList().length > 0)
                        {
                            ko.utils.arrayForEach(outeritem.sectionList(),function(item){

                                item.isSectionSelected(false);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(extendedAttributeModel.filterListOptions(), function(item) {
                        item.isSelected(false);
                        if(item.childObjects()!=null){
                            ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.childObjects(), function(item) {
                                item.isSelected(false);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsCountLabel("");
                extendedAttributeModel.OptionsSelectedCount(0);
                extendedAttributeModel.isOptionsSelected(false);
            };



            return extendedAttributeModel;
        }
    };


};
```

In short,it replicates the drag one option.Kindly tell me what I am missing??

Comment: Where is your view model?

Comment: I've had problems like this also.  Fix was to ensure each template has a single top level item, and no whitespace outside of it - ie: `<script type="text/html" id="..."><div> <!-- whatever content --> </div></script>`

Comment: @JamesThorpe,i will check it...then i will tell you...what's the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're making use of the [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) library.  I've had problems in the past where the templates had whitespace outside of any elements - it's noted on the project's page also:

> Note2: When using named templates, you will have the best results across browsers, if you ensure that there is only a single top-level node inside your template with no surrounding text nodes. Inside of the top-level nodes, you can freely use whitespace/text nodes. So, you will want:

```
<!-- good - no text nodes surrounding template root node -->
<script id="goodTmpl" type="text/html"><li data-bind="text: name">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</li></script>

<!-- bad -->
<script id="badTmpl" type="text/html">
<li>
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</li>
</script>
```

Comment: Huh... what a weird bug. I actually implemented this functionality myself (not using knockout-sortable) and had the exact same issue. This fixed it.